# Select Latin American Spanish voice for translate feature?

Tags: macos, internationalization, accessibility

In several macOS apps, I can select text, and then control-click and select "Translate ..." from the context menu. For example, here are screenshots from TextEdit.

[image]  

    
[image]

For Spanish, it speaks with the pronunciation style from Spain, instead of Latin America. Is there any way to select the voice, so I can hear a Spanish closer to what I'm trying to learn?

I know that the operating system has those different voices, because when I write software for macOS, I can pick voices with languages like "es-ES" (Spain) or "es-MX" (Mexico). The latter is closer to what I want to hear.

Comment: Have you tried going to Accessibility preferences > Speech and setting the system voice to the one you want?

Comment: @TomGewecke If you mean System Preferences > Accessibility > Spoken Content > System Voice, then yes I tried that and it had no effect. My system is in English, so setting it to a Spanish voice didn't seem right, but I messed around with anyway.